# Windows Phone 8 HRESULT: 0X80042706

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 Application that uses the map control. I have followed the tutorial, but I keep geeting the messagebox error: HRESULT: 0X80042706. Here is the code from the tutorial

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        map.ColorMode = MapColorMode.Light; map.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Road; map.LandmarksEnabled = true; map.PedestrianFeaturesEnabled = true; map.ZoomLevel = 17;
        routeQuery.TravelMode = TravelMode.Walking; routeQuery.QueryCompleted += rq_QueryCompleted;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    } 

...

void rq_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e) {       
        if (null == e.Error)        {            
            //Recommended way to display route on map                   
            Route MyRoute = e.Result;                  
            MapRoute MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);                   
            map.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);        
        }       
        else           
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured:\n" + e.Error.Message); 
    }
```

I tried to search what kind of error `HRESULT: 0X80042706` was from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd208031%28v=prot.20%29.aspx), but I have no idea what that meant.

I even tried to switch the if condition to `e.Error == null`, but still no good. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you registered for Bing Maps and been provided with an authentication key which you've then added to your XAML?

Comment: The tutorial says I'm not using Bing Maps, only the Maps API of Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Have you specified the capabilities of map in app manifest? If not do so like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Yes I have. I also have added the namespace in the Page's XAML and code-behind file

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your device does not support CHAP authentication while connecting to Virtual Disk Service (i.e. Maps)

This is because you don't have an authentication id from Microsoft.
Follow the details here ( for wp8 maps another authentication is required)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207033(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I believe this only applies to publishing your app, not testing on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error from the same tutorial, and found it was due to no internet access to my PC (and hence no map data).  Restored Internet access and the error resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please once check your Manifestfile and select Capability option click in ID_CAP_MAP.